# Multiple Context using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have an issue always getting null when getting multiple contexts using hooks.

app.js

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { AppContext } from "./AppContext";

export default function App() {
  const { layout } = useContext(AppContext);

  console.log("layout", layout);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For the sourcecode, you can see here
https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-wood-pj33g

Comment: docs: "You still need a <MyContext.Provider> **above** in the tree to provide the value for this context."

Comment: Do mind showing which part should I put the provider? @xadm

Comment: `<App/>` is rendered as react root (in index), should not be context consumer, should not use `useContext`